# How to remove auto generated info in VS code by material design (dart)? (please refer the image)

Tags: visual-studio-code

[This auto generated info when you press enter to select any widget.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GefEf.png)

The problem is I am coding and this info pop up and it blocks my code, I have to use mouse and click somewhere else to remove that.

I checked the settings but its too overwhelming there. Didn't understand how to shut this off.